# get iTh view of listView in android?

Tags: android, listview

I'd like to get the i-th view of listView.
(I have not seen an example to call getView, I have only seen getView implemented for call-back.)

What I am trying to do is :
I'm going to create a asyncTask for each row and pass the view that holds the progressBar to the task.
The task will update the progressBar while it performs the task.

Hence, I need a way to iterate all the views(not just visible views) in a listView.

Comment: Please provide more information. When are you trying to fetch this View, is the View visible?

Comment: @Sam: I updated the question with goal

Comment: @Eugene: well, ListView re-uses row views, means if there are 100 items, it doesn't mean there will be 100 views for rows (typically).

Comment: @Adil Soomro: that's what I feared.. What is the alternative to listview that doesn't re-use its views? (Since my list won't go over 20 items or so)